# Is it possible to make index on alias column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT name, LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO(name, 'variablethings')  as percent
FROM from my_table 
order by percent desc
```

`my_table` have a one million data.

This query is too long because 'percent' column is alias.
Is it possible to make index on alias column in this query?
or any other solution about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  MySQL does not allow you to create an index on an expression.  One possibility is to switch databases to one, such as Postgres, that does have this functionality.

That might be too extreme.  Instead, create a new table with the `select` statement and then create an index on `percent`.  You will take the performance hit once, when you create the table, but you can run it many times.

Comment: .. but then you can read from that new table many times without the performance hit.